# MySQL error: "NUMBER" is not valid at this position, expecting: BIT, BOOL, BOOLEAN, DATE, TIME, ENUM

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table in MySQL workbench as just a regular DDL operation and not a stored procedure

```
CREATE TABLE Authors (
   AuthorID NUMBER GENERATED AS IDENTITY,
   FirstName VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
   LastName VARCHAR2 (30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (AuthorID)
);
```

I get the following error:
"NUMBER" is not valid at this position, expecting: BIT, BOOL, BOOLEAN, DATE, TIME, ENUM...
I am unable to read the rest of it as it is cut off

I also try to create other tables using VARCHAR2 and no matter what datatype I put for the first line, I get the same error. I try using VARCHAR2, CHAR etc instead of number and I get the same error.

I also have the following error in my console: 16:36:59 CREATE TABLE Authors (    AuthorID NUMBER GENERATED AS IDENTITY,    FirstName VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,    LastName VARCHAR2 (30) NOT NULL,    PRIMARY KEY (AuthorID) )   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER GENERATED AS IDENTITY,    FirstName VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,    LastName V' at line 2    0.00049 sec

Google says this error points to either reserved words, missing data, mistyped commands or obsolete commands. Is it possible that this is an obsolete command? This is an oracle 12c homework assignment so it should be up to date. I try eliminating "generated as identity" and I still get the above error.

The file I've opened with this code is from my professor and maybe it is not associated with the database I've created in Mysql as I don't see how the two are related.

When I right click and try to add the table that way, it tries to change the datatype to int.

Comment: Since when MySQL has IDENTITY?  Have you tried to read MySQL Documentation???  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing MySQL and Oracle databases.  The equivalent create table statement in MySQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE Authors (
   AuthorID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   FirstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   LastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (AuthorID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

USE numeric instead of NUMBER in my sql, problem solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).